# Unexpected token import in app.bundle.js angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to build an Angular 2 app from scratch with Webpack. After adding all the files and finishing all the configurations, i build the project. while building it didn't give any error. but when i open the index.html the text loads while giving an error in the console as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import  in app.bundle.js:47"

this is the place where it results the import error

```
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    import 'core-js'; **//this is line 47**
    import 'reflect-metadata';
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

the repo of my project [enter link description here](https://github.com/TRomesh/Tweety)

Any reason why im getting this error?.I've tried almost everyting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `webpack.config.js` which caused webpack to not use any loaders and simply concatenate the raw typescript source files into the bundle.

The property is `module.loaders` not `module.loader`.

You will need something like

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],

    root: path.resolve('src')
}
```

where path is imported with `const path = require('path');`
I don't know why it doesn't infer paths from the working directory...

Comment: now im getting an error like "Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app.module"

Comment: I updated my answer. It builds now but Webpack config is quite unpleasant.

Comment: im still getting the same error Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app.module"